# Binding TextBox to a Windows Form not working

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, data-binding

**My environment is:**

Windows 11
Windows Form App created by the Windows Forms App template of Visual Studio 2022.

**Problem:**

I have a simple Windows Form with only a Textbox and a Button.
I am trying to update the Textbox text with new data whenever the button is pressed.

The binding works when the Windows Form is loaded. The text "12.34" appears in the Textbox.
But when I click on the button, the Textbox is not updated with the new data.
Here is my code:

```
namespace WatchChart;

public partial class WatchForm:Form
{
    public class BidAsk
    {
        public string? BidString { get; set; }
    }

    public WatchForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void MyForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var bid = new BidAsk() { BidString = "12.34" };
        bidTextBox.DataBindings.Add(nameof(TextBox.Text), bid, nameof(BidAsk.BidString));
    }

    private void displayButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var bidask = new BidAsk();
        bidask.BidString = "23.45";
    }
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated,
Charles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first potential issue is that you need the bound variable to be a *member* of the main form (instead of making a local `var` inside the methods). The other potential issue is making sure to enable two-way binding. The `BidString` property should be implemented similar to the `BidAsk` shown in order to fire a `PropertyChange` event whenever its value changes.

```
class BidAsk : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string _bidString = string.Empty;
    public string BidString
    {
        get => _bidString;
        set
        {
            if (!Equals(_bidString, value))
            {
                _bidString = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string? propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

[image: screenshot]

---

**Test**

Here's the code I used to test this answer::

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm() => InitializeComponent();
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        BidAsk = new BidAsk();

        textBoxBid.DataBindings.Add(
            propertyName: nameof(TextBox.Text), 
            dataSource: BidAsk, 
            dataMember: nameof(BidAsk.BidString));

        buttonDisplay.Click += onClickButtonDisplay;
    }
    BidAsk BidAsk { get; set; }

    private void onClickButtonDisplay(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Test string gobbledegook
        var marklar = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 11);
        BidAsk.BidString = marklar;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new `BidAsk` (let's call it `bidAsk1`) on load, and binding to that. Then on the button click, you are creating another `BidAsk` (`bidAsk2`) and setting the content. Your textbox is still bound to `bidAsk1`, not `bidAsk2` so it will not be updated.

Try keeping a reference to the bound object:

```cs
namespace WatchChart;

public partial class WatchForm:Form
{
    public class BidAsk
    {
        public string? BidString { get; set; }
    }

    private BidAsk bid;

    public WatchForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void MyForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bid = new BidAsk() { BidString = "12.34" };
        bidTextBox.DataBindings.Add(nameof(TextBox.Text), bid, nameof(BidAsk.BidString));
    }

    private void displayButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bid.BidString = "23.45";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your replay, Andrew. However, no cigar.  I made your changes, and it still does not work.

Comment: Ah, you also need `BidAsk` to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface so the textbox can be notified when the bound value has changed

Comment: Have a [look at the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)